# How to do a proper keyword search

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

If I search for the term 'tfo' in the cell value 'TFO_xyz' then the result should be TRUE. 
If I search for the term 'tfo' in the cell value 'TFO systems' then the result should be TRUE.

If I search for the term 'tfo' in the cell value 'spring TFO' then the result should be TRUE.

BUT if I check 'tfo' in the cell value 'Platform' then I want the result as FALSE

I have used the formula `=IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*tfo*"),"TRUE","FALSE")`, but this wont give result as FALSE when I check 'tfo' in the word 'Platform'

NOTE:

Platform should be false because tfo is coming in between a word. I'm looking result as True for cell values with just the word tfo like in tfo<‌space>America or TFO_America or <‌space>TFO systems. But I want FALSE result for the words Platform and portfolio because in these two words the term tfo comes in between alphabets.

Comment: Please update your question with an explanation of why *Platform* should be false.

Comment: I recommend to use regular expressions to distinguish such complicated rules. Any formula will not distinguish between a `tfo` in `Platform` and `TFO_xyz`

Comment: maybe using the `matchcase` if the ones you want to be true are always with caps and the ones which not, are not. That would be the simple way but risky.

Comment: Platform should be false because tfo is coming in between a word. i am looking result as True for cell values with just the word tfo like in tfo<space>America or TFO_America or <space>TFO systems. but i want FALSE result for the words Platform and portfolio because in these two words the term tfo comes in between alphabets.

Comment: regular expressions like!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim x As Long: x = 1

With Sheet1

    Do While x <= .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If VBA.Left(.Cells(x, 1).Value, 3) = "tfo" Or VBA.Right(.Cells(x, 1).Value, 3) = "tfo" Then

            .Cells(x, 2).Value = True

        End If

        x = x + 1

    Loop

End With
```

Comment: Also include Option Compare Text statement

Comment: If you want to complement your code, please edit the answer instead of commenting.

Comment: I don't see why this should be a Sub and not a UDF (User Defined Function).

Comment: This won't fulfill the OP's request, fails at e.g. "xyz TFO abc", or "tform", where tform is a fictitious sensible word.

Comment: If you give up avoiding VBA and depending on Excel-Functions only, then using regex would be a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see two dimensions of complexity in your question:

- Where does the key word occur in the text (beginning, middle, end)
- What are the characters that separate words.

The first one is fixed size, you need to handle three cases. The second one depends on the number of characters you want to accept as delimiters. Below I assumed that you accept space and underscore, however, you may expand this set by inserting more `SUBSTITUTE` function calls.

In my table, $A2 is the cell in which you search for the keyword, while B$1 contains the keyword.

To standardize the separator character, you need the formula:

```
B2=SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," ")
```

To check if the string starts with the keyword:

```
C2=--(LEFT($B2,LEN(B$1)+1)=B$1&" ")
```

To check if the string ends with the keyword:

```
D2=--(RIGHT($B2,LEN(B$1)+1)=" "&B$1)
```

To check if the keyword is in the middle of the string:

```
E2=--(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($B2)," "&UPPER(B$1)&" ",""))<LEN($B2))
```

To evaluate the above three cases:

```
F2=--(0<$C2+$D2+$E2)
```

If you want to use a single cell, combine the formulas into:

```
G2=--(0<--(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," "),LEN(B$1)+1)=B$1&" ")+--(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," "),LEN(B$1)+1)=" "&B$1)+--(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," "))," "&UPPER(B$1)&" ",""))<LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," "))))
```

It is not very readable in the end but I don't think there was an easier solution using Formulas only.

Note: If you want to modify the set of characters accepted as delimiters, add more `SUBSTITUTE` function calls to B2, then copy the Formula of F2 into notepad and replace $C2 with the formula of C2, etc., then replace $B2 with the updated Formula of B2.

**Update**

Building on the idea in Ron Rosenfelds comment to tigeravatar's answer, the formula can be simplified (the beginning, middle, ending cases can be joined):

```
=--(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" "&UPPER($B2)&" "," "&UPPER(B$1)&" ",""))<LEN($B2))
```

After substituting $B2 with its formula:

```
=--(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" "&UPPER(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," "))&" "," "&UPPER(B$1)&" ",""))<LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_"," ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula. This assumes that word tfo will be at the beginning or end
Just make sure to place appropriate cell names where i have 'A2' in the formula

```
=IF(OR(PROPER(LEFT(A2,3))="tfo",PROPER(RIGHT(A2,3))="tfo"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

**Test Cases Below:**

[image]

Comment: As I understand, it can be in the middle, too, like "xyz TFO abc", in this case your formula would fail.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Just wanted to mention that it is failing for the below test cases: (Note: Please read ‘<space’ as a space bar. i.e. <space>TFO<space> means ‘  TFO  ‘.

Failed test cases are:
<space>TFO<space>
<space>tfo<space>
_TFO_
_tfo_
*TFO*
*tfo*

Comment: @DevBg If you have got your answer, please upvote the correct answer that solved your problem so that this thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return true if `TFO` is at the beginning or end of any given word, or by itself, in the text string.  It also checks every word in the text string, so TFO can be at beginning, middle, or end.  The formula assumes that if a word starts or ends with TFO, then the result should be TRUE (as is the case for `tfoAmerica` so same rule would apply to `tform`), else FALSE.

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" tfo","tfo "}," "&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_"," ")&" ")))
```

Here are its results:

[image]

**EDIT**:

In the event that the result should only be TRUE if TFO is found by itself, then this version of the formula will suffice:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" tfo "," "&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_"," ")&" "))
```

Image showing results of second version:

[image]

Comment: Fails at "abc tform" where tform is a fictitious sensible word.

Comment: @z32a7ul How does it fail? It processes it using the same logic it would process "tfoAmerica" where it returns TRUE because "tfo" is specifically at the beginning of the word.  The proposed formula returns TRUE as expected per OP's description of requirements.

Comment: Yes, it returns true but I would expect false if tform was a sensible word as I assumed in my comment. If plaTFOrm should be rejected, then TFOrm should be rejected, too. Both contain TFO but not as a keyword but accidentally, as part of another sensible word.

Comment: @z32a7ul If that is truly the case, then tfoAmerica *must* return FALSE.  However, per OP's description of requirements, it should return TRUE.  I have extrapolated that to mean that anytime a word specifically starts or ends with "tfo", the formula will return TRUE to meet that requirement.  I have also verified there is no valid/sensible English word that starts tfo, so I think it's a moot point anyway.

Comment: @tigeravatar In the comments the OP writes tfo<space>America. I don't think you can (1) validate that there is no sensible word starting with tfo, especially if the local jargon of the company, acronyms, and non-English words may also occur; (2) be sure that "tfo" is always the keyword that you search for and it won't be changed e.g. to "post" or "non".

Comment: @z32a7ul but in his Question, the OP writes `tfoAmerica`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The OP wanted to write tfo<space>America in the question, too. However, the formatting rules of questions and of comments are different. If you click on edit below the question, you can check that the plain text is tfo<space>America. Unfortunately, SO's formatting tools interpret it as some special formatting, like double stars means bold, backtick is for code, etc. Maybe < and > have some meaning, too.

Comment: @z32a7ul Ah, I see.  That's tricky and I've run into that problem in some of my own posts.  I corrected it here by adding a ZWJ character after the first angle bracket.

Comment: i think =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" tfo "," "&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_"," ")&" ")) is serving the purpose but not for *tfo*, *tfo, abc tfo*

Comment: @DevBg The string you've demonstrated is comma delimited, so just need to add that delimiter by including a second Substitute: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" tfo "," "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_"," "),","," ")&" "))`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to spend sometime to know your data and create a white-list.
Since there is no easy way to properly do fuzzy search in strings.

```
Function TFO_Search(strText As String) As Boolean

Dim ArryString      As Variant
Dim ArryWhitelist   As Variant

' Create a White-List Array
ArryWhitelist = Array("TFO_", "TFO ", "_TFO", " TFO", "tfoAmerica")

For Each ArryString In ArryWhitelist
If InStr(UCase(strText), UCase(ArryString)) > 0 Then  'force to UPPER CASE
    TFO_Search = True
    Exit Function
Else
    TFO_Search = False
End If
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on VBA, then regex is a more flexible solution.

There is a good summary, of how to use them in VBA: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

For your keyword search problem I wrote the following:

```
Option Explicit

' Include: Tools > References > Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vbscript.dll\3)


Public Function SearchKeyWord(strHay As String, strNail As String, Optional strDelimiters As String = " _,.;/", Optional lngNthOccurrence As Long = 1) As Long ' Returns 1-based index of nth occurrence or 0 if not found
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = CreatePattern(strNail, strDelimiters)
    Dim rgxKeyWord As RegExp: Set rgxKeyWord = CreateRegex(strPattern, True)
    Dim mtcResult As MatchCollection: Set mtcResult = rgxKeyWord.Execute(strHay)
    If (0 <= lngNthOccurrence - 1) And (lngNthOccurrence - 1 < mtcResult.Count) Then
        Dim mthResult As Match: Set mthResult = mtcResult(lngNthOccurrence - 1)
        SearchKeyWord = mthResult.FirstIndex + Len(mthResult.SubMatches(0)) + 1
    Else
        SearchKeyWord = 0
    End If
End Function

Private Function CreateRegex(strPattern As String, Optional blnIgnoreCase As Boolean = False, Optional blnMultiLine As Boolean = True, Optional blnGlobal As Boolean = True) As RegExp
    Dim rgxResult As RegExp: Set rgxResult = New RegExp
    With rgxResult
        .Pattern = strPattern
        .IgnoreCase = blnIgnoreCase
        .MultiLine = blnMultiLine
        .Global = blnGlobal
    End With
    Set CreateRegex = rgxResult
End Function

Private Function CreatePattern(strNail As String, strDelimiters As String) As String
    Dim strDelimitersEscaped As String: strDelimitersEscaped = RegexEscape(strDelimiters)
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(^|[" & strDelimitersEscaped & "]+)(" & RegexEscape(strNail) & ")($|[" & strDelimitersEscaped & "]+)"
    CreatePattern = strPattern
End Function

Private Function RegexEscape(strOriginal As String) As String
    Dim strEscaped As String: strEscaped = vbNullString
    Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To Len(strOriginal)
        Dim strChar As String: strChar = Mid(strOriginal, i, 1)
        Select Case strChar
        Case ".", "$", "^", "{", "[", "(", "|", ")", "*", "+", "?", "\"
            strEscaped = strEscaped & "\" & strChar
        Case Else
            strEscaped = strEscaped & strChar
        End Select
    Next i
    RegexEscape = strEscaped
End Function
```

Once you have the above in a Module, you can insert formulas like the following:

```
=SearchKeyWord($A1,"tfo")
```

where A1 contains e.g. "tfo America".

As a third parameter, you may specify, which characters you want to treat as delimiters, by default they are space, underscore, comma, dot, semicolon and slash.

The return value is the position of the nth occurrence of the keyword, where n is the value of the fourth parameter (default: 1), or 0 if not found.

To check if the keyword is present in A1, compare the result to 0, which means not found:

```
=--(SearchKeyWord($A1,"tfo")<>0)
```